# How can I resolve FileNotFoundError in Camelot pdf Python when reading tables?

Tags: python, pdf

Tables.py :

```
import camelot 

space_table = camelot.read_pdf('space.pdf', pages='all', flavor='stream')

print(space_table)
```

I have this error : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'space.pdf'

I don't know why there is this error, 'space.pdf' is in the directory where Tables.py is.

Can someone helps me ?

I want recover the tables of pdf file.

Comment: Can you try with 'absolute path
C:/path/to/space.pdf'

Answer (score 0):

Check the current working directory, the current working directory might not be correct.

You can check it with:
print(os.getcwd())

With the above command, check if the file is located in the directory. If it is not correct, you can add it before the file name.